# expected expression before ',' token

Tags: ubuntu, makefile

I was trying to install brackets on Ubuntu **15.10** but it said there were unresolvable dependencies because I did not have `libgcrypt` so I searched for it and downloaded it, its uncompiled so I did:

```
./configure
```

And when I type make it gives me the error specified in the topic. All the errors are in the makefile for example:

```
./mkerrcodes.h:39:5: error: expected expression before ‘,’ token
   { , "GPG_ERR_EEXIST" },
     ^
```

It is my first time on this site, also I don't have very much experience with linux at all, I have been using windows all my life.

Comment: Did you try simply `sudo apt-get install libgcrypt`?  Or maybe `libgcrypt11` or 20?

Comment: unable to locate package

Comment: libgcrypt20 is already the newest version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest and best solution is to simply use the `libgcrypt` package from your system package manager.  On Ubuntu this is either `libgcrypt20` or `libgcrypt11`.  You may need the `-dev` version of either package as well, depending on the requirements of the software you're trying to install.

Answer (score 1):

Allo,

To install brackets on ubuntu I've used [that](https://itsfoss.com/install-brackets-ubuntu/) and it worked perfectly. Brackets has binaries available for Debian based distributions. There is also a PPA by Webupd8 team.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/brackets
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install brackets
```

For your `libgcrypt` problem, you may try manually from another repository as mentionned [here](https://www.jbnet.fr/systeme/linux/linux-installer-brackets-sous-debian-8-jessie-64bits.html):

```
command wget http://ftp.acc.umu.se/mirror/cdimage/snapshot/Debian/pool/main/libg/libgcrypt11/libgcrypt11_1.5.4-3_amd64.deb
command dpkg -i libgcrypt11_1.5.4-3_amd64.deb
```

and then start again with the brackets installation

```
command dpkg -i Brackets.1.3.Extract.64-bit.deb
```